# Which Hecke algebra is used in representation theory?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, hecke-algebras, langlands-program

Which Hecke algebra is used in representation theory or more specifically in the study of Langlands's conjecture ?

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecke_algebra_of_a_locally_compact_group), the Hecke algebra is constructed from a locally compact topological group and its closed subgroup.

While from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecke_algebra), the Hecke algebra is defined in terms of Hecke operators which are coming  from Modular forms.

This makes me confused.

Are the above two definition literally and mathematically equivalent ?

If not, which one is used in the study of Local/Global Langlands's conjecture ?

Any explanation will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are used and they are basically equivalent.  What I'm going to say is technically incorrect in some details but the general idea is right.

To make life easy, assume $f$ is a modular cusp form for $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ which is a normalized eigenfunction of all Hecke operators $T_p$.  There is a way (actually several, slightly inequivalent ways) to associate $f$ to an automorphic form $\phi: \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Q) \backslash \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb A) \rightarrow \mathbb C$.  Let $G = \operatorname{GL}_2$.  The function $\phi$ lives inside the space $L^2(G(\mathbb Q)Z_G(\mathbb A) \backslash G(\mathbb A))$ and generates an irreducible representation $\Pi$ inside there.

Let $G_p = G(\mathbb Q_p)$ and $K_p = G(\mathbb Z_p)$.  There are unique irreducible, admissible representations $\pi_p$ of $G_p$ and a representation $\pi_{\infty}$ of $G_{\infty} = G(\mathbb R)$ such that $\Pi$ contains the "infinite tensor product" representation $\otimes_{p \leq \infty} \pi_p$ as a dense subspace (some work needs to be done to make sense out of an infinite tensor product).  Assume each representation $\pi_p$ of $G_p$ has a nonzero vector fixed by $K_p$.

Let $H_p = \mathscr C_c^{\infty}(K_p \backslash G_p/K_p)$ be the convolution ring of locally constant and left and right bi-$K_p$ invariant complex valued functions on $G_p$.  This is one of the kinds of Hecke algebras you were considering.  These particular Hecke algebras turn out to be commutative rings with unity.  Let $H_{\operatorname{fin}}$ be the infinite tensor product of the rings $H_p : p < \infty$.

The function $\phi$ lies in $\otimes_{p \leq \infty} \pi_p$ and in fact is itself equal to an infinite tensor product $\phi = \otimes_{p \leq \infty} \phi_p$ with $\phi_p \in \pi_p$.  The Hecke operators $T_{p^n} : n \in \mathbb N$ scale the cusp form $f$, but if we identify $f$ with the automorphic form $\phi$, then the $T_{p^n}$ affect only the component $\phi_p$.  In fact, $T_{p^n}$ identifies with a certain element in $H_p$, and $H_p$ is generated as an algebra by the $T_{p^n}$.

In this way, the tensor product of the "local Hecke algebras" $H_p$ form the "global finite Hecke algebra" $H_{\operatorname{fin}}$, which can also be thought of as being generated by the operators $T_{p^n}$, for $p$ prime and $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation

Comment: No mention of the word 'convolution' ?

Comment: I was looking back my old posts. There is a possible typo in the 2nd para of your answer. It should be the double coset $L^2(G(\mathbb Q)/Z_G(\mathbb A)\backslash G(\mathbb A))$.